# Large data.tree causes plot() to error

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I'm trying to build an org chart from a data.frame in r using the data.tree package.

As far as i can tell i have constructed the tree correctly, but when I try to `plot()` the `data.tree` object (which `print()`s fine) I get an error:

```
abort(0) at jsStackTrace@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:5:22110
stackTrace@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:5:22258
abort@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:28:10656
nullFunc_iii@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:5:662065
a8@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:21:31634
iC@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:9:83383
aD@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:9:102098
uF@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:9:173805
pG@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:9:204484
xc@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:11:740
http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:28:403
ccallFunc@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:5:15982
http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/viz-0.3/viz.js:47:42
renderValue@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/grViz-binding-0.8.4/grViz.js:38:27
http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/htmlwidgets-0.7/htmlwidgets.js:625:30
forEach@[native code]
forEach@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/htmlwidgets-0.7/htmlwidgets.js:55:21
http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/htmlwidgets-0.7/htmlwidgets.js:551:14
forEach@[native code]
forEach@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/htmlwidgets-0.7/htmlwidgets.js:55:21
staticRender@http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/htmlwidgets-0.7/htmlwidgets.js:549:12
http://localhost:30899/session/viewhtml2fdc215a4edd/lib/htmlwidgets-0.7/htmlwidgets.js:638:38
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this is because of the size of the tree? Did you use styling? Pls add some reproducible code. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I have just started using the data.frame package a couple of days ago, but came across the same problem with some of my trees - print(tree) worked but plot(tree) gave a similar error message to yours. So far, I could always resolve the issue by removing special characters like single and double quotation marks from the input data. Thus, the plot function appears to be sensitive to certain symbols or special characters ... maybe a starting point for your search for a solution?